# send a file to a client after long wait

Tags: java, servlets, download

i've a java servlet that makes some reports. When a user choose a report it makes a query on a db and stream the xls report to the client. All in synchronous way. The problem is that sometimes i've a lot of records to fetch from the db and i would like to give a better user experience, allowing the user to do something else while the report is processing and popping out in some way the link when the process is finished. Is there a java library or some techniques to avoid the long waiting and achieve that goal?

Right now i've prepared a piece of code that in a asynchronous way completes the report and sends an email to the registered client, with the url from wich download the file, but it has to be replaced with something else because i can no longer communicate by email.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just work with multiple threads, having a thread for each process.

Answer (score 1):

heres my take on this, i dont know of a single library that will exactly match you needs, youd probably need some custom development here.

- I believe you have implemented async service that on completion sends
  out an email for notification. Instead of sending out an email, let
  that thread update a job table of some sort -- an entry in a db table
  or some application/session scoped map.
- Have a servlet/restful ws
- expose that job table at some url.  Poll the url at regular
  intervals. Ajax poll is a standard feature in js libraries JQuery,
  Prototype.
- When you get a response that some report is complete, show
  some popup or may be a facebook you-have-notification kind of thing
  on the client side.

i have not considered authentication/authorization issues here, you need to take care of that as well.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

A multithreaded client server program to download my image files.
Since there are four files to download the client makes 4 connection attempts. This is not limited to 4 but the files sent by the FileServer will get repeated after the fourth attempt. The save dialog and file saving is done in different threads so as to not hamper the file downloading.

Here is the FileServer...

```
public class FileServer {
    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    final String[] fileNames = {
            "C:\\Users\\clobo\\Pictures\\Arpeggios\\Ex 1.jpg",
            "C:\\Users\\clobo\\Pictures\\Arpeggios\\Ex 2.jpg",
            "C:\\Users\\clobo\\Pictures\\Arpeggios\\Ex 3.jpg",
            "C:\\Users\\clobo\\Pictures\\Arpeggios\\Ex 4.jpg"

    };

    public void start() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("Waiting for client message...");

        while (!exec.isShutdown()) {
            try {
                for (final String fileName : fileNames){
                     final Socket conn = socket.accept();

                    exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            sendFile(conn,fileName);

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
                if (!exec.isShutdown())
                    log("task submission rejected", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Shutting down server...");
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    private void log(String msg, Exception e) {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.WARNING, msg, e);
    }

    public void sendFile(Socket conn, String fileName) {
        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        if (!myFile.exists()) {
            log("File does not exist!",null);
        }

        // file does exist
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("AbsolutePath:" + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("length: " + myFile.length());

        if (myFile.exists()) {
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                conn.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(myFile);
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("IOException Error", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileServer fs = new FileServer();
        fs.start();
    }
}
```

here is the FileServerClient...

```
public class FileServerClient {

    private final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Frame myFrame = new Frame();
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();

    public void receiveFileFromServer() throws Exception{

        Socket sock = null;
        InputStream socketInputStream = null;
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 7777;

        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {

            sock = new Socket(host, port);
            socketInputStream = sock.getInputStream();
            System.out.println("Connection successful...");

            // recieve the file
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socketInputStream);

            // file from server is deserialized
            final File myfile = (File) ois.readObject();
            fileList.add(myfile);

            // deserialized file properties 
            System.out.println("AbsolutePath: " + myfile.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("FileName:" + myfile.getName());
            System.out.println("length" + myfile.length());
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    saveFile(myfile);

                }
            });

        }

    }

    private void saveFile(File myfile) {
        FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(myFrame,
                "Choose Destination for "+ myfile.getName(), FileDialog.SAVE);
        fileDialog.setDirectory(null);
        fileDialog.setFile("enter file name here");
        fileDialog.setVisible(true);

        String targetFileName = fileDialog.getDirectory()
                + fileDialog.getFile() + ".jpg";

        System.out.println("File will be saved to: " + targetFileName);

        copyBytes(myfile, targetFileName);
    }

    private void copyBytes(File originalFile, String targetFileName) {

        try {
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(originalFile);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetFileName);
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log("IOException Error", e);
        }

    }

    private void log(String msg, Exception e) {
        Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.WARNING, msg, e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        FileServerClient client = new FileServerClient();

        client.receiveFileFromServer();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an asynchronous request from the client. Lets assume that you client is an html page. When the user selects a report and clicks on 'submit' you could fire an ajax request with the report parameters (jquery can be useful for this).  It would be good to keep a section on the user homepage that says something like 'prepared reports'. The client can then goto the prepared report section to download the report. As specified in the comments above, you may also have to implement a popup that informs the user that the requested report is ready. the popup is shown when the ajax requests returns successfully. However, the client may have logged out by the time the report finishes, so it may be a good idea to make the download link available again in the 'prepared reports' section when the user logs in.